# Existence and uniqueness of solutions; extending a finite interval $[t_{0}, t_{1}]$ to $[t_{0}, \infty)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, set-theory, nonlinear-system

so I'll start with my main question, in short, giving details below:

If I'm using a theorem to prove the existence and uniqueness of solutions to $\dot{x} = f(x,t)$ which states "$J = [t_{0}, t_{1}]$ *is a finite, closed interval*", and I find that all other conditions apply ánd that $t_{0} < t_{1}$ can be chosen arbitrarily (large), is it correct to assume that solutions exist on $J = [t_{0}, \infty)$? **No, right?** My colleagues disagree and say it ís possible, but I find that it violates the assumption of a finite interval thus making the proof invalid.

---

Specifically, the dynamical system was given as

$$ \dot{x}(t) = t^{2} \cdot x(t) $$

and the theorem used (based on the book *Nonlinear Systems* by Khalil) was given as

"**Lemma V.2** *If $f$ is piecewise continuous in $t$ and globally Lipschitz in $x$, then the system has a unique solution on $[t_{0}, t_{1}]$ for any initial state $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$.*"

where the piecewise continuity is trivially satisfied, and Lipschitz continuity is defined as

"*Throughout this section, we consider systems of the form*

$$\dot{x} = f(t, x), \quad x(t_{0}) = x_{0}, \\
f : J \times D → \mathbb{R}^{n}, \quad J = [t_{0}, t_{1}], \quad D \subset \mathbb{R}^{n} \: domain.$$

*Note that J is a **finite**, closed interval (see Section I).*"

and

"**Lemma IV.2.** *If $f$ and $[\partial f / \partial x]$ are both continuous, then $f$ is locally Lipschitz. If there furthermore exists a $B > 0$ s.t.
$$ \left\Vert \left[ \frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x} \right] \right\Vert \leq B, \quad \forall x \in D, t \in J,$$
then $f$ is also Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $L = B$. [...]. It is globally Lipschitz (uniformly in $t$) if furthermore $D = \mathbb{R}^{n}$.*"

Now we can show that Lemma IV.2 holds with $B =t_{1}^{2}$ on the domain $D = \mathbb{R}$, making the function globally Lipschitz for any choice of $t_{1}$. Thus Lemma V.2 is satisfied with $D = \mathbb{R}$ and $J = [t_{0}, t_{1}]$. **However**, I believe that this is all that we can conclude. My colleagues give the argument that since $t_{1}$ can be chosen arbitrarily large, we can say $J = [t_{0}, \infty)$. Is this correct and if so/not, why? I believe it is not correct since this interval is no longer finite.

---

Any insight into this question would be greatly appreciated: since we are teaching this course to students I would like to have a cohesive and properly justified argumentation; thanks for reading and sorry for the long post!

**EDIT:**

I wanted to clarify that what I'm mainly interested in is whether the argumentation using Lemma V.2 and Lemma IV.2, and the definitions given, is correct or not: I 100% believe solutions exist on $[t_{0}, \infty)$ and that we can show the solutions don't blow up in finite time or any other theorem, but that's not really my point: is the proof given **here** valid, and if so, why does it not matter that we violated the condition that $J$ must be finite?

The reason I am asking is that I think is that we need to remove this condition on $J$ being finite on our formula sheet unless one of you knows why this condition is there in the first place. Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: I think global existence is ensured by the fact that the solution cannot explode in finite time.  
Then, a part the fact that for equation of the form
$$
x'(t)=a(t)x(t)
$$
we have an explicit formula for the solution, it suffices to knwo that 
x'(t)\leq a(t) |x(t)|
and to apply the Gronwall Lemma.

In general, for vector fields that are ``sublinear'' in the state variable, global existence is ensured...

Hope it can help.

Comment: If you want to use your argument, suppose by contradiction that the solution explodes in finite time, let's say $\overline t$ (since a solution is not globally defined only if it explodes, see for example Theorem 3.1, pag 45,Hale Verduyn Lunel, Introduction to Functional Differential Equations). The solution is thus defined on $[t_0,\overline t)$ and 
$$ 
\lim_{t\to \overline t^-} x(t)=+\infty
$$
Choose a $t_1>\overline t$, use the Khalil's book result, leading to a contradiction.

Comment: Hi @MatteoDR, thanks for your answer: I updated my questions to give some clarification. I'm not really looking for an argumentation for why solutions do exist for $[t_{0}, \infty)$, which I believe is the case, I am interested in finding out why it would be allowed to let $t_{1}$ "grow to infinity" as for me this violates one of the conditions of the Lemma's used in our proof: I believe we either need to update the Lemma (remove the condition of $J$ being finite) or add another Lemma in a similar vein to showing solution cannot blow up in finite time, but my colleagues disagree.

Comment: I think yes, the Lemmas you have are enough. . Suppose by contradiction that the solution is not globally defined, i.e., for some $t$ the solution is not defined in $t$. Then use your lemma for a $t_1$ strictly larger that $t$,

Comment: If you want a direct/constructive proof, that's another point.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a solution on $[t_0, t_1]$ for arbitrarily large values of $t_1$, then there is a solution on $[t_0, \infty)$.  Namely, $x(t)$ is equal to its value in the solution on $[t_0, t_1]$ for any $t_1 > t$.  There is no ambiguity because of the uniqueness.

Comment: I am not sure I quite follow, what do you mean exactly by "$x(t)$ is equal to its value in the solution on $[t_{0}, t_{1}]$"? $x(t)$ is a trajectory, i.e. a mapping $x : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $, how can it be "equal to its value in [...]"? I also don't quite see how the uniqueness comes into play: my gripe is that the theorem clearly states that $J$ is a finite interval. The interval $[0, \infty)$ is not finite, thus this means the theorem does not apply, right? That's where my ambiguity lies.